# Enforce use of lodash-es instead of lodash?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, eslint

Since `@types/lodash-es` requires `@types/lodash`, `@types/lodash` is always suggested as import for lodash functions.

How could I enforce on a project to only use `@types/lodash-es` ?

I know I could use the es-lint `no-restricted-imports` rule :

```
'no-restricted-imports': [
    'error',
    { patterns: ['lodash'] },
],
```

But is there some other way ?

Comment: Why isn't that es-lint rule what you need?

Comment: @Cerbrus Maybe it is ! Just asking if there were any alternative !